# Does boto3 have an option to override the DNS lookups?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am looking at something like the `curl --resolve` option which I find very helpful to test a particular IP behind the DNS. Any other option from python or urllib would be helpful too!

Comment: Are you wanting to override a service endpoint? That can be specified when creating a boto3 session object.

Comment: yes make the service endpoint hit a particular IP.. can you share an example?

Comment: `boto3.client('ec2', endpoint_url="http://1.1.1.1/myendpoint")`

Comment: ah but this can work only for http not https.. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that boto3 was using urllib3. So I went with this solution:

The urllib3.connection module subclasses httplib.HTTPConnection under the same name, having replaced the .connect() method with one that calls my implementation. In turn, this delegates to urllib3.util.connection.create_connection(). It is perhaps easiest to patch that function:

```
from urllib3.util import connection


_orig_create_connection = connection.create_connection


def patched_create_connection(address, *args, **kwargs):
    """Wrap urllib3's create_connection to resolve the name elsewhere"""
    # resolve hostname to an ip address; use your own
    # resolver here, as otherwise the system resolver will be used.
    host, port = address
    if host == my_endpoint:
        host = my_ip

    return _orig_create_connection((host, port), *args, **kwargs)


connection.create_connection = patched_create_connection
```

and you'd provide your own code to resolve the host portion of the address into an ip address instead of relying on the connection.create_connection() call (which wraps socket.create_connection()) to resolve the hostname for you.